# Button in navigation drawer can't listen click event

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, navigation-drawer

I have a relative layout in my navigation drawer, the problem is when
I click a button from navigation drawer I can't get toast. So I think my button not responding.

My layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- main screen -->
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<!-- navigation drawer -->

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/whatYouWantInLeftDrawer"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:background="@android:color/black" >
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:background="#303592"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and here is My full code of deskboard activity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;

public class DeskboardActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
RelativeLayout leftRL;
RelativeLayout rightRL;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Button first;
String fragment_title;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deskboard);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    leftRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.whatYouWantInLeftDrawer);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    first = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);


    drawerLayout.setClickable(true);
    first.setClickable(true);
    first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //displayView(0);
            Toast.makeText(DeskboardActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
    }
     /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new UpdatesFragment();
            fragment_title = "Updates-BrahmShakti";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            setTitle(fragment_title);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(leftRL);

        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    public  void onOpenLeftDrawer(View view)
    {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(leftRL);
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.deskboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post complete code.

Comment: try to set new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: Change `getApplicationContext()` to `YourActivity.this`. It might works.

Comment: I make that changes doesn't changed anything. above is my fullcode for that activity.

Comment: I have test Your Code is Working fine.

Comment: Everything working, but the button click event not working.

Comment: Thanks i forgot that i have a list view with the gravity="start" just after the button in my layout. I removed listview and everything working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Isn't it supposed to be

```
        first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // View.OnClickListener.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
              // activityName.this insteade of getApplicationContext.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:background="#303592"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="runToast"
       />


      first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runToast(v)

        }
    });

   public void runToast(View v) {
   Toast.makeText(activity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta glad to heard this from you :)